# What might explain a rush of euphoria before enduring physical pain?

Tags: consciousness, pain, oxytocin

What neurological or physiological response would work fast enough to anesthetize or provide a euphoric sensation during or in advance of a body trauma event such as being involved in a car or bike accident, a non-lethal shark attack, falling off a ladder, etc.?

Comment: This will probably be down to a sudden rush of adrenaline which is why some people thrive on extreme sports. [See this article for more information](http://www.fitday.com/fitness-articles/fitness/body-building/what-is-an-adrenaline-junkie.html)

Comment: I super appreciate the edit, but I'd still like some references that this experience is actually common.